# Ruby on Rails div_for vs <div>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. In my erb files, is there any reason to use the `div_for` helper over just typing out the `<div>` tags and setting the properties as HTML? What advantage is there to using `div_for`, and is there a recommended best practice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the main reason people use the `div_for` helper is because it can accept an array of ActiveRecord objects as an argument. That way it becomes a short-hand combination of a loop iterator and a tag generator.

```
<%= div_for(@people, :class => "foo") do |person| %>
    <%= person.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone! I didn't realize that div_for makes it easier to iterate through a variable. That said, most of the time I'll probably just use the div tag, and div_for for circumstances where I'm creating a lot of div's based on some sort of list.

Answer (score 6):

`div_for` does some "magic" for you, in that it sets the class and ID of the element it generates.

There is no reason to choose it over a simple `<div>` tag if you don't intend to use those properties, or intent to use different values for them.

There is no strong convention either way. I've been writing Rails code for years and have literally never used it, put it out of your mind, it doesn't matter. There are far, far more important decisions to make, like choosing [erb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) or [haml](http://haml.info/) or [slim](http://slim-lang.com/), or deciding whether to adpot [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). Decisions that will fundamentally alter the way you write Rails code.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, rails 'helpers' are like training wheels on a bicycle.  They help when you are just starting out,  but at some point,  you jettison the training wheels and start doing wheelies,  sliding skids,  and jumping homemade ramps.

But helpers vary,  some are so helpful you never get rid of them,  others get in the way when you want to start doing wheelies.

If you find using any particular 'helper' is cramping your style,  stop using it!